# Color de encabezado al exportar

Tags: vba, ms-access

Tengo este código para exportar una tabla de 4 columnas a excel:

```
  Public Function Exportar()
    
    Dim ruta As String
    
    ruta = "C:\Users\Desktop\FICHERO.xlsx"
    
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Tabla1", ruta, True
    
    End Function
    
    Sub ejecu()
    
    End Sub
```

Una vez exportado abres el fichero y todo correcto, pero me gustaría ponerle al encabezado de la tabla un color distinto para diferenciarlo del resto de los datos.

No sé si se le puede añadir el color desde el código.

Creo que se puede con `.Interior.Color`

He ido probando con varias cosas, pero nada.

Comment: Hola. Lo que pasa es que ahí lo que haces es, a través del VBA de Access, exportar datos en formato Excel, no es que estés realmente controlando a Excel. Para lograr lo que requieres no te servirá lo que tienes ahí o la propiedad que mencionas ya que eso último es del objeto Excel. Para realizar lo que necesitas requieres hacer varias cosas adicionales como usar un objeto Excel, detectar el archivo creado, y recién ahí modificar las celdas que requieres, pero no sé si entiendes eso de trabajar con el objeto Excel.

Comment: Entonces con código VBA desde access no se puede hacer? Aunque sea en dos macros, una que exporte y otra que cambie el color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo para que entiendas lo que es manejar el objeto Excel. Es simple justamente para que sea fácil entenderlo, ya tú mejóralo y/o adáptalo a tus necesidades. Obviamente puedes usar otras propiedades.

```
Sub ejm()

Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim miLibro As Excel.Workbook
Dim mihoja As Excel.Worksheet
Dim UltimaColumna As Long
Dim miExcel As String

miExcel = "C:\Users\eavj6\Documents\ExportarExcel.xlsx"
 
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Tabla1", miExcel, True

Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set miLibro = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(miExcel)
Set mihoja = miLibro.Worksheets("Tabla1")

UltimaColumna = mihoja.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

mihoja.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, UltimaColumna)).Interior.ColorIndex = 36

appExcel.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Saludos

Comment: Gracias!! Si lo ejecuto tal cual (cambiando la ruta) me sale: "No se ha definido el tipo definido por el usuario"

Comment: Perdón, olvidé mencionar que tienes que activar las referencias a "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Objects Library".

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error viene de las referencias que tengo, son estas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]